# How to download multiple files from GCP using Google.Cloud.Storage in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform

Today images are saved in separate folders in GCP, so it is necessary to do more than one query to search for them. To optimize the query, the ideal would be to save the images in a single folder and bring them all in a single query. The Google.Cloud.Storage package doesn't seem to provide the option to download a list of files, is there a way to do this or an alternative?

Comment: No, you can't. It's per object download. You can create a loop and also parallelize (multi thread) your calls to speed up the process.

Comment: Tip: folders do not exist in Google Cloud Storage. The part you think is a directory/folder name is just characters in the object name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Google.Cloud.Storage package doesn't seem to provide the option to download a list of files, is there a way to do this or an alternative?

We don't provide it in the library because it's not provided in the underlying API. If we were to try to add some sort of parallelization over the top of the underlying API, chances are it would be a bad fit for some or even most users.

The client is thread-safe, so it's absolutely fine to start multiple downloads in parallel, whether using synchronous calls in separate threads, or (probably better) just multiple asynchronous calls using `Task.WhenAll` to determine when they're all complete.

Note that the location of the objects within GCS won't affect this at all - the directory structure is effectively synthetic; downloading two objects with names that happen to have a common prefix is no quicker than downloading two objects with entirely different names. Using a single folder *would* make it easier to find all the objects to download, however, using a `ListObjects` call with a suitable prefix.